# Tube mesh generation in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've created a procedural mesh script while watching one of Freya Holmér's improvised live course vods, and re purposed the code to create a procedural tube mesh with subdivision and plenty of other niche features.

*But*, after looking over the code and the lesson, I still cannot for the life of me figure out why sometimes I will get an:

> argument out of range exception

...and sometimes I won't depending on the level of subdivision; also, entire faces wont be generated by the script.

### TL;DR Problems list:

- Argument out of range exception (Depending on level of subdivision).
- Entire sides/faces of the tube mesh will not be generated, even when no errors are provided.

These problems are stemming from line 154 in the `UpdateTris()` method.

### Code

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
using OpenNexus.ExtraGizmos;
#endif

using OpenNexus.BaseMath;
using OpenNexus.MeshFormat;

namespace OpenNexus.Procedurals
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
    public class TubeMesh : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private MeshFilter filter;
        private Mesh mesh;

        public List<Vector3> Points = new List<Vector3>()
        {
            new Vector3(0, 0, 0),
            new Vector3(0, 1, 1),
            new Vector3(0, 0, 2)
        };

        [Header("Bezier Data")]
        public Precision BezierPrecision = Precision.Fast;

        [Header("Tube Data")]
        [Range(0.01f, 1f)]public float Radius = 0.01f;
        [Range(3, 32)] public int Segments = 8;
        [Range(3, 6)] public int Subdivisions = 3;

        [Header("Mesh Data")]
        public ProceduralMesh2D BaseProceduralMesh = new ProceduralMesh2D();
        public List<Vector3> Vertices;
        public List<int> Tris;

        private void OnEnable()
        {
            if (!GetComponent<MeshRenderer>()) // Check for and add missing mesh renderer.
                gameObject.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();

            if (filter == null) // Check for and assign mesh filter variable.
                filter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();

            if (mesh == null) // Check for and instantiate a new mesh object.
                mesh = new Mesh();

            mesh.name = "TubeMesh"; // Set name to mesh object.
            filter.sharedMesh = mesh; // Set MeshFilter's shared mesh variable to new mesh object.
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            /*
                Data reset
            ------------------------------
             */

            // Reset base mesh data.
            BaseProceduralMesh.Vertices = new List<Vertex>();
            BaseProceduralMesh.LineIndex = new List<int>();
            
            // Reset mesh data.
            Vertices = new List<Vector3>();
            Tris = new List<int>();

            /*
                Data update
            ------------------------------
             */

            // Update base mesh.
            UpdateBaseMesh();

            // Update mesh data.
            UpdateVertices();
            UpdateTris();
        }

        private void LateUpdate() => UpdateMesh();

        private BezierPoint GetBezierPoint(int index)
        {
            float _t = index / (Segments - 1f);
            BezierPoint _bp = BezierMath.QuadraticBezier(Points, BezierPrecision, _t);
            
            return _bp;
        }

        private void UpdateBaseMesh()
        {
            // Generate base vertices.
            for (int i = 0; i < Subdivisions; i++)
            {
                float _point = i / (float)Subdivisions;
                float _radius = _point * Floats.TAU;
                Vertex _vertex = new Vertex(VectorThrees.UnitVectorByAngle(_radius) * Radius);

                BaseProceduralMesh.Vertices.Add(_vertex);
            }

            // Generate base LineIndexes.
            for (int i = 0; i < BaseProceduralMesh.VertexCount; i++)
            {
                BaseProceduralMesh.LineIndex.Add(i);
            }
            BaseProceduralMesh.LineIndex.Add(0);
        }

        private void UpdateVertices()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Segments; i++)
            {
                BezierPoint _point = GetBezierPoint(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < BaseProceduralMesh.VertexCount; j++)
                {
                    Vertices.Add(_point.LocalToWorldPosition(BaseProceduralMesh.Vertices[j].Point));
                }              
            }
        }

        private void UpdateTris()
        {
            for (int s = 0; s < Segments - 1; s++)
            {
                int _root = s * BaseProceduralMesh.VertexCount;
                int _rootNext = (s + 1) * BaseProceduralMesh.VertexCount;

                for (int i = 0; i < BaseProceduralMesh.EdgeCount; i+=2)
                {
                    int _lineA = BaseProceduralMesh.LineIndex[i];
                    int _lineB = BaseProceduralMesh.LineIndex[i + 1];

                    int _currentA = _root + _lineA;
                    int _currentB = _root + _lineB;

                    int _nextA = _rootNext + _lineA;
                    int _nextB = _rootNext + _lineB;

                    Tris.Add(_currentA);
                    Tris.Add(_nextA);
                    Tris.Add(_nextB);

                    Tris.Add(_currentA);
                    Tris.Add(_nextB);
                    Tris.Add(_currentB);
                }
            }
        }

        private void UpdateMesh()
        {
            mesh.Clear();
            mesh.SetVertices(Vertices);
            mesh.SetTriangles(Tris, 0);
            mesh.RecalculateNormals();
        }

#if UNITY_EDITOR

        private void OnDrawGizmos()
        {
            // Draw psudo mesh with gizmos.


            /*
                Draw segment/edge loops
            -------------------------------------
             */

            for (int i = 0; i < Segments; i++) // Debug each segment, and what their 2D mesh segment should look like.
            {
                BezierPoint _point = GetBezierPoint(i);
                WireGizmos.DrawWireCircle(_point.Position, _point.Rotation, Radius, Subdivisions);
            }

            Gizmos.color = Color.red;
            for (int i = 0; i < Vertices.Count; i++) // Debug each vertex.
            {
                Gizmos.DrawSphere(Vertices[i], 0.01f);
                Handles.Label(Vertices[i], "\n\nVertex: " + i + "\n\nVertex position:\n" + Vertices[i].ToString());
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < Tris.Count; i++)
            {
                Gizmos.DrawLine(Vertices[Tris[i]], Vertices[Tris[(i + 1) % Tris.Count]]);
            }
        }

#endif
    }
}
```

---

I've already looked over my code compared to the code in the video, it's fundamentally the same, with the main differences being, how I'm creating the 2D mesh format for the script to work with, and the structure of the code.

After looking back at what they had done compared to mine, I just don't see how I'm running into this issue.

### Things I've tried

- Change the loop iteration `i+=2` -to- `i++` (This spits out the exception, but generates the first section of the tube before getting stuck between the second vertex in the next segment, and vert 0).

Every suggestion I try from this question, I will update the "Things I've tried..." list.

Please let me know if I need to clarify anything in this post, and if you wish to see the other classes/structs referenced in this script.

Comment: Always post code here and not in foreign silos where links can break with time

Comment: _"sometimes I will get an: argument out of range exception"_ - have you tried using a debugger.

Comment: _"I've created a procedural mesh script while watching one of **Freya Holmér's** improvised live course vods, and **re purposed the code**...to create a procedural tube mesh with subdivision and plenty of other **niche features**...I've already looked over my code **compared to** the code in **the video, it's fundamentally the same** ... **After looking back** at **what they had done** compared to mine**, I just `don't see how I'm running into this issue`"_ - consider re-wording your question.  Currently your  tone makes it sound that it is somehow Freya Holmér's fault.

Comment: I don't know who is responsible for what code but the code in `OnEnable` could quite easily be in `Start` or replaced entirely with `[RequiresComponent(...)]`.  Also is it really necessary to regenerate _vertices, edges_ and _faces_ **60 times a second**?  Even if your tube was _vibrating_ only the _vertices_ need be updating I would have thought

Comment: What is ProceduralMesh2D?

Comment: @MickyD
I've stated that I "re purposed" the code, "adding niche features", this points it to be on my end a code slip up some where. I did use a debugger previously when I was figuring out how to get everything to work on a procedural basis, but not this just yet, thank you for reminding me. I'm responsible for the code as a single developer. And the mesh updates because I'm going to be using this mesh as a laser for VR interactions (and no I will not be using a line renderer as I've already prototyped with one before.

Comment: @shingo
`ProceduralMesh2D` is a class I created to act as the `Mesh2D` Scriptable object shown in the lesson I watched, that way I could work with code that is closer to the tutor's and hopefully make more sense of it while working with a fully procedural mesh.

Comment: Ya let us know how you go in the debugger.  You can set a conditional breakpoint for any wacky values.

Answer (score 0):

After a day of resting, and the a couple of hours of testing different values and questioning the code. I've found the problem.

## The *real* issue

The nested for loop in the `UpdateTris()` method was going up by twos assuming I was making a hard edge mesh with pared vertices. This caused the loop to skip over an entire face of the mesh, and causing the

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException

...when the `Subdivision` value was an even number.

## My solution

I had to bring it back to the default single iteration (since I was trying to make a smooth lighting mesh), the second issue with the for loop was the iteration limit `BaseProceduralMesh.LineCount` needing to be subtracted by one since that was causing another

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException